# Request session username does not update between routes

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I am writing a project based on React, Express and MongoDB. I have reailzed the login and register function. The react is listening on port 5173, while the Express is listening on port 3000. Below is my login/register component.

```
import "../App.css";
import React from 'react';
import "react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setUsername, setPassword } from '../reducer/userSlice';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Form(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const username = useSelector((state) => state.user.username);
  const password = useSelector((state) => state.user.password);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (props.formName === "Register") {
      const formData = {
        username,
        password
      };

      fetch("http://localhost:3000/reg", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })

      navigate("/login");
    } else {
      const formData = {
        username,
        password
      };

      fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            navigate("/home");
          } else {
            return response.json();
          }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data && data.message) {
            alert(data.message);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
      <h2 className="display-5">{props.formName}</h2>

      <form className="column g-3 needs-validation" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input className="form-control" id="nameInput" type="text" required value={username} onChange={(e) => {
            return dispatch(setUsername(e.target.value))
          }} />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input className="form-control mb-3" type="password" required value={password} onChange={(e) => {
            return dispatch(setPassword(e.target.value))
          }} />
        </div>

        <div className="col-12">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{props.btnName}</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And it worked, I can send data to the login router as listed below.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const md5 = require("md5");
const { UserModel } = require("../database/db.js");

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

router.post("/login", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    let { username, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username, password: md5(password) });

        if (user) {
            res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful" });
            req.session.username = user.username;
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ message: "Login failed, Please Try again" });
        }
        
        console.log(req.session);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I added username to the session cuz I want to reailze the session control in other components like add records. However, when I tried to access the username in session in other route, it showed it did not exist.

This is my home page router. I should have the access to the req.session.username, however it's undefined.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { AccountModel } = require('../database/db.js');

router.get("/home", async (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.username) {
        try {
            const records = await AccountModel.find({ userId: req.session.username });
            res.json(records);
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
    console.log(req.session);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Below is my unfinished home page component, it should show the records based on the session username.

```
import "../App.css";
import React from 'react';
import "react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function List() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/home", {
            method:'GET',
            credentials: "include"
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status !== 401) {
                    navigate("/login")
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            })
            .then((data) => {
                if (data && data.message) {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <h2 className="col-xs-6">记账本</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="accounts">
                <div className="panel panel-success">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        Date
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <div className="col-xs-6">
                            Name
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-2 text-center">
                            Type
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-2 text-right">
                            Amount
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-2 text-right">
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="note-container">
                            <p>This is a note.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="panel panel-danger">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        Date
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <div className="col-xs-6">
                            Name
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-2 text-center">
                            Type
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-2 text-right">
                            Amount
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-2 text-right">
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="note-container">
                            <p>This is a note.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried many ways to solve, however they did not work. I noticed that when I login, the session table in mongoDB is empty, which is in contrary to my previous experiences. But I did not find any possible problem in my code. So please help me solve this problem, thank you.